# Which way is better to compare two strings in Python? I want to know which one is faster

Tags: python, string, set

Suppose two variables a and b stores two strings, I want to compare whether the two strings are same or not. In Python, the typical way should be `a == b`. I believe the time complexity of that is O(min(m,n)), where m and n are the length of string. But if I compare them in this way a in {b} (I add string b to a set and check if string a in that set), will the time complexity be O(1), regardless of the length of strings in a and b?

Comment: You could benchmark it, but `==` is almost certainly faster.

Comment: Set containment is expected to be O(1) because it doesn't depend on the size of your set, but you're talking about the size of the string, which is a different variable. It still has to examine the content of the string: it isn't magic.

Answer (score 5):

No, as the `in` operator first computes the hash of the string (linear complexity) and then does another comparison if an element with the same hash is in the set (again, linear complexity). So, `a == b` is your best bet, as it skips the computation of the hash and avoids the construction of the set.

The constant time complexity of the `in` operator is with regards to the length of the set. It is still linear in regards to the length of the string.

**However**, the following results seem to disagree:

```
$ python3 -m timeit "'aaa' == 'aaa'"
20000000 loops, best of 5: 18.9 nsec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit "'aaa' == 'bbb'"
10000000 loops, best of 5: 22.1 nsec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit "'aaa' in {'aaa'}"
20000000 loops, best of 5: 17 nsec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit "'aaa' in {'bbb'}"
20000000 loops, best of 5: 16 nsec per loop
```

A slightly altered example seems to make more sense...

```
$ python3 -m timeit "a = 'aaa'; b = 'bbb'; a in {b}"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 63 nsec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit "a = 'aaa'; b = 'bbb'; a in {a}"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 55.7 nsec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit "a = 'aaa'; b = 'bbb'; a == b"
10000000 loops, best of 5: 30.1 nsec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit "a = 'aaa'; b = 'bbb'; a == a"
10000000 loops, best of 5: 27 nsec per loop
```

The resaon for this can be found in the disassembly of the code:

```
from dis import dis

def a():
    'aaa' in {'aaa'}

def b():
    x = 'aaa'
    'aaa' in {x}

print(dis(a))
print(dis(b))
```

Yields:

```
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('aaa')
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (frozenset({'aaa'}))
              4 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
None
 12           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('aaa')
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

 13           4 LOAD_CONST               1 ('aaa')
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              8 BUILD_SET                1
             10 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             12 POP_TOP
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Since we are using only literals for the first approach, python can make one of its (extremely rare) optimisations and use LOAD_CONST instead of having to construct the set during runtime.

For more realistic code however, this is no longer the case and the expensive BUILD_SET has to be used.

Comment: I suppose you mean that it is not for sure that one is faster than the other? Perhaps in some case, the in operator could be better...

Comment: @SamuelWen Strings are already highly optimized. If there was a way sets could make string equality faster then that would already be incorporated in the regular method.

Comment: Checking the bytecode with `dis` you can see that `a in {a}` has to use `BUILD_SET` while `'aaa' in {'aaa'}` can use `LOAD_CONST ... (frozenset({'aaa'}))`.

Comment: @Matthias Exactly. So for code "in the wild", the second series of samples make a lot more sense, as it seems unlikely that the string in the set will be a literal. Quite an interesting finding!

Answer (score 1):

No. This just hides the check. To check if a value is in a set, it first needs to hash the member it is checking. Then, if it finds a match for the hash it needs to call their implementation of equals to verify if the matching hash was just a false positive. So now you end up with O(m+n+min(m, n)).

That being said, since strings are such a core part of computer science they have a lot of various optimizations behind the scene. Some strings might have  already been hashed ahead of time and that value was cached. Or maybe a and b point to the same string so it can exit early. Or their lengths are different so it can quickly exit. Attempting to add your own optimizations for something as important as strings will likely only make it more difficult for the system you are working to help you.

Answer (score -2):

Time complexity-wise, it will be faster to compare `a is b` for strings than `a == b`, given one can exclude that none of them is `NaN`.

Okay, I thought this is "smart" but see below a counterexample why using `is` is fatal - by @khelwood! The article suggested by @JohnColeman is also very interesting. (Thanks!)

Comment: Wouldn't this only check if they were the same object and not that they contain the same data? We're referring to strings, not numbers.

Comment: @Locke Even with numbers `is` will only work in special cases.

Comment: @Locke Python strings are unique. So equal strings are the same object. (Which is not so necessarily in other programming languages - but Python strings work like this).

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim Is this guaranteed by the language specification or an implementation detail?

Comment: @Matthias with numbers, 1.0 == 1 but not 1.0 is 1. So with numbers, one should use `=`. But Python strings are a special case.

Comment: No, it is quite possible to have two strings with the same content that are not the same object. `is` is not equivalent to `==`.

Comment: @khelwood can you give an example in Python?

Comment: See [this blog post](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/string-interning-in-python-a-hidden-gem-that-makes-your-code-faster-9be71c7a5f3e) on string interning for an example of two equal strings that fail the `is` test.

Comment: Tried it in IDLE (3.9.1) with `x = 'AB'` and `y = x[:1] + x[1:]`. I got `True` for `x == y` and `False` for `x is y`.

Comment: `a='!'*10` `b='!'*10`

Comment: @khelwood Thanks! Convincing! One always learns something ...

Comment: @khelwood interesting example which seems to behave differently if the non-alphabetical `'!'` is replaced by something like `'A'`

Comment: @JohnColeman Python (in some implementations) has extra interning for short alphabetic strings.